# Visit website page from Array data, Retrieve ElementID, populate new array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

**OBJECTIVE**

Pull in exchange rate data for various currencies.

**APPROACH**

1. Select Active Sheet and copy currencies-to-be-converted into an array (e.g ["EUR", "GBP", "USD"]
2. Open Browser and visit currency conversion website
3. Loop through different currencies and extract currency conversion factors
4. **Append conversion factors to an array**
5. Repopulate excel with newest conversion factors

**CODE**

```
Sub retreiveCurrencies()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim locals() As Variant
Dim exchangeArray() As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim IE As Object


'Select currencies to convert
Sheets("APPENDIX - CURRENCY CONVERTER").Activate
locals = Array(ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B15"))
'This should return locals = ["EUR", "GBP, "USD"]

'Prep Internet Explorer
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = False

Do While IE.Busy And Not IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

'Loop through currencies and retreive exchange rates. Paste rates into exchangeArray
For i = LBound(locals()) To UBound(locals())
    IE.Navigate "http://www.usforex.com/currency-converter/" & locals(i) & "/usd/1.00/false"
    exchange = IE.Document.GetElementById("converterToAmount").innerText
    'exchangeArray = [] QUESTION: What should I add here to create an array of exchange rates?
Next i

'Paste exchange rate array into currency conversion column
ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D15") = exchangeArray()


End Sub
```

**QUESTIONS/ISSUE(S)**

1. For line `IE.Navigate "http://www.usforex.com/currency-converter/" & locals(i) & "/usd/1.00/false"` I receive a "Type Mismatch". **Do I need to convert `locals()` to text?**
2. How do I loop through  `IE.Document.GetElementById("converterToAmount").innerText`and append retrieved values to a new array `exchangeArray()`

*NOTE: There may be many errors in this code. I am a VBA newbie and this is my attempt at a more complex script.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this line:

> ```
> locals = Array(ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B15"))
> ```

This isn't creating an array of values from `ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B15)` - it is creating an array of `Range` objects with only one element in it.  This means that in the line of code that actually throws the mismatch, `locals(i)` is a `Range`.  Since you have multiple cells in that `Range`, the default member (`.Value`) returns a 2D array of `Variant`, which can't be concatenated into a string.

You need something more like this instead:

```
locals = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B15").Value

'...

'Loop through currencies and retreive exchange rates. Paste rates into exchangeArray
For i = LBound(locals, 1) To UBound(locals, 1)
    ie.navigate "http://www.usforex.com/currency-converter/" & locals(i, 1) & "/usd/1.00/false"
    exchange = ie.document.getElementById("converterToAmount").innerText
    'exchangeArray = [] QUESTION: What should I add here to create an array of exchange rates?
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I now receive a "Subscript out of range" on line "  IE.Navigate "http://www.usforex.com/currency-converter/" & locals(i) & "/usd/1.00/false"  ".


Not quite sure how this affects a URL parameter

Comment: @kidlogic Ooops - forgot to change that line to 2D indexing.  See the edit.

Comment: thank you for the clarification- looks like I need to extend my VBA skills. This has solved the issue w.r.t not throwing errors. However, the I.E is only pulling in (I assume) the last value in the array (which is "USD", not "EUR" or "GBP"). I will dive deeper to solve this. Thank you!


EDIT:  Solved by adding anoter "Do While IE.Busy..." loop within the For loop you've proposed